# How to create one to one relationship and foreign key in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

What is the difference between  `Has One`, `Has Many` and `Belong To`

I have 3 Models

- `User`
- `Profile` Where `profile` and `user` should have `one to one` relationship
- `Category` Where `category` should be `foreign key` to `user`

```
type User struct {
gorm.Model
Email *string
Name string
...
}

type Profile struct {
gorm.Model
Phone string
Address string
...

}

type Category struct {
gorm.Model
Name string

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `User` `Has One` `Profile`

```
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   Email *string
   Name string
   Profile Profile //this is the key different
}
type Profile struct {
   gorm.Model
   UserId int //this is important
   Phone string
   Address string
}
```

For `Profile` `Belong To` `User`

```
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   Email *string
   Name string
}
type Profile struct {
   gorm.Model
   UserId int //this is important
   User User //this is the key different
   Phone string
   Address string
}
```

For `User` `Has Many` `Category`

```
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   Email *string
   Name string
   CategoryList []Category
}
type Category struct {
   gorm.Model
   UserId int //this is important
   Name string
}
```

Edit: UserId field will become your foreign key.

If you want gorm to automatically create table for you, you can use `AutoMigrate` in main.go

```
err := db.AutoMigrate(your_model_package.User{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Comment: These examples should be in the gorm doc, good job BlackLotus and thanks for sharing